# Use a simulation on a armature

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I am trying to animate a person falling down the stairs, but that would be a lot to hand animate. Is there any way to simulate them falling with all their limbs moving?

Comment: I guess the best way would be to create a ragdoll. But that's a question better to be solved with a tutorial rather than a simple answer here. Google "Blender ragdoll" and there might be some solutions, for example this YT video [How To Make Any Rig Into a Rag Doll in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUmIKWVrHZU) or this site [Blender Secrets: Ragdoll (the easy version)](https://www.blendersecrets.org/secrets/ragdoll-tutorial-blender) and there are also addons: [Ragdoll Tools](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/ragdoll-tools)